# Using ORM when i am going to insert value in the database it gives me following error->" Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, frameworks, laravel-7

```php
$user = new User();

$user->name = 'sarthak';
$user->email = 'sarthak@bitfumes.com';
$user->password = 'notnull';
$user->save();
```

But the server says

> "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found";

Comment: Looks like you're missing a php namespace import. You need to tell PHP where to find `App\Http\Controllers\User` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You need to use a correct model namespace in your controller file:

`use App\Model\User;` or `use App\User;`

Hope it helps.

Comment: use App\User;   --->Works

Comment: Okay, it depends on you folder architercute. Please, mark answer as approved, if it hepls you. Thanks.